# Pandas pivoting a dataframe by years

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to pivot a dataframe as follows:

- I have an hourly dataframe for several years in long format with a variable V1
- I would like to have a column for each year of the variable V1

  ```
   date  = ['2015-02-03 21:00:00','2015-02-03 22:30:00','2016-02-03 21:00:00','2016-02-03   22:00:00']
   value_column = [33.24  , 500  , 34.39  , 34.49 ]

   df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':value_column}, index=pd.to_datetime(date))

   print(df.head())

                      V1 
   index                                     
   2015-02-03 21:00:00  33.24   
   2015-02-03 22:30:00  500   
   2016-02-03 21:00:00  34.39   
   2016-02-03 22:00:00  34.49
  ```

Expected result:

```
                V1_2015  V1_2016
02-03 21:00:00    33.24     33.49
02-03 22:00:00    500       33.49
```

So far I tried this which gets me close but no there:

```
df['year'] = df.index.year
df=df.set_index(['year'],append=True)
df=df.unstack(level=1)

                         V1
                         2015    2016
    2015-02-03 21:00:00  33.24   
    2015-02-03 22:00:00  500   
    2016-02-03 21:00:00          34.39   
    2016-02-03 22:00:00          34.49
```

Basically I would like to align month day hours so that the V1 variable can be compared accross different years. Any idea how to do that efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the index into a string so you can delete the year and minutes like so:

```
df['year']=df.index.year

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['index']=df['index'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[5:13])

df.set_index('index',inplace=True)
df.pivot(columns='year')
```

output:

```
              V1       
year        2015   2016
index                  
02-03 21   33.24  34.39
02-03 22  500.00  34.49
```